# Json parsing Issue using objectmapper library in swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, objectmapper

I am facing issue with parsing response from server side. I get response in this format 
1.) [image]
For first image my model class is working fine. In this I don't null

2.) [image]
For second image response my Model class is not working it's giving nil after parsing.In this I get null in array

My Model class for my api response is this

```
class GetTodayMyKpiResponse: Mappable{

var status: String?
var myKpiMonth: MyKpiMonthResponse?
var myKpiWeek: MyKpiWeekResponse?


required init?(map: Map){

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    status <- map["status"]
    myKpiMonth <- map["myKpiMonth"]
    myKpiWeek <- map["myKpiWeek"]
}

}

class MyKpiMonthResponse: Mappable{
var myKpiMonthYear: Double?
var myKpiMonthDetailList: [MyKpiMonthDetailResponse]?
var myKpiMonthList: [MyKpiMonthListReponse]?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    myKpiMonthYear <- map["myKpiMonthYear"]
    myKpiMonthDetailList <- map["myKpiMonthDetail"]
    myKpiMonthList <- map["myKpiMonthList"]
}
}

class MyKpiMonthDetailResponse: Mappable{
var myKpiMonthDetailOutletCode: String?
var myKpiMonthDetailUnitTiers: [String]?
var myKpiMonthDetailTargetUnits: [String]?
var myKpiMonthDetailBonusIncentive: Double?
var myKpiMonthDetailOutletName: String?
var myKpiMonthDetailModelName: [String]?
var myKpiMonthDetailMonth: String?
var myKpiMonthDetailType: Double?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    myKpiMonthDetailOutletCode <- map["myKpiMonthDetailOutletCode"]
    myKpiMonthDetailUnitTiers <- map["myKpiMonthDetailUnitTiers"]
    myKpiMonthDetailTargetUnits <- map["myKpiMonthDetailTargetUnits"]
    myKpiMonthDetailBonusIncentive <- map["myKpiMonthDetailBonusIncentive"]
    myKpiMonthDetailOutletName <- map["myKpiMonthDetailOutletName"]
    myKpiMonthDetailModelName <- map["myKpiMonthDetailModelName"]
    myKpiMonthDetailMonth <- map["myKpiMonthDetailMonth"]
    myKpiMonthDetailType <- map["myKpiMonthDetailType"]
}
}

class MyKpiMonthListReponse: Mappable {
var myKpiMonthMaxUnit: Double?
var myKpiMonthDate: String?
var myKpiMonthBonusAmount: Double?
var myKpiMonthActivatedUnit: Double?
var myKpiMonthMinUnit: Double?
var myKpiMonthCurrentUnit: Double?
var myKpiMonthBonusStatus: String?
var myKpiMonthOutletName: String?
var myKpiMonthOutletAddress: String?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    myKpiMonthMaxUnit <- map["myKpiMonthMaxUnit"]
    myKpiMonthDate <- map["myKpiMonthDate"]
    myKpiMonthBonusAmount <- map["myKpiMonthBonusAmount"]
    myKpiMonthActivatedUnit <- map["myKpiMonthActivatedUnit"]
    myKpiMonthMinUnit <- map["myKpiMonthMinUnit"]
    myKpiMonthCurrentUnit <- map["myKpiMonthCurrentUnit"]
    myKpiMonthBonusStatus <- map["myKpiMonthBonusStatus"]
    myKpiMonthOutletName <- map["myKpiMonthOutletName"]
    myKpiMonthOutletAddress <- map["myKpiMonthOutletAddress"]
}
}

class MyKpiWeekResponse: Mappable{
var myKpiWeekDetail: [MyKpiWeekDetailResponse]?
var myKpiWeekList: [MyKpiWeekListResponse]?
var myKpiWeekYear: Double?
var myKpiWeekMonth: Double?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {

    myKpiWeekDetail <- map["myKpiWeekDetail"]
    myKpiWeekList <- map["myKpiWeekList"]
    myKpiWeekYear <- map["myKpiWeekYear"]
    myKpiWeekMonth <- map["myKpiWeekMonth"]
}
}

class MyKpiWeekDetailResponse: Mappable{
var myKpiWeekDetailEndDate: String?
var myKpiWeekDetailUnitTiers: [String]?
var myKpiWeekDetailOutletName: String?
var myKpiWeekDetailStartDate: String?
var myKpiWeekDetailType: Double?
var myKpiWeekDetailModelName: [String]?
var myKpiWeekDetailTypeOfReward: String?
var myKpiWeekDetailOutletCode: String?
var myKpiWeekDetailTargetUnits: [String]?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    myKpiWeekDetailEndDate <- map["myKpiWeekDetailEndDate"]
    myKpiWeekDetailUnitTiers <- map["myKpiWeekDetailUnitTiers"]
    myKpiWeekDetailOutletName <- map["myKpiWeekDetailOutletName"]
    myKpiWeekDetailStartDate <- map["myKpiWeekDetailStartDate"]
    myKpiWeekDetailType <- map["myKpiWeekDetailType"]
    myKpiWeekDetailModelName <- map["myKpiWeekDetailModelName"]
    myKpiWeekDetailTypeOfReward <- map["myKpiWeekDetailTypeOfReward"]
    myKpiWeekDetailOutletCode <- map["myKpiWeekDetailOutletCode"]
    myKpiWeekDetailTargetUnits <- map["myKpiWeekDetailTargetUnits"]
}
}

class MyKpiWeekListResponse: Mappable {
var myKpiWeekBonusStatus: String?
var myKpiWeekEndDate: String?
var myKpiWeekActivatedUnit: Double?
var myKpiWeekStartDate: String?
var myKpiWeekMinUnit: Double?
var myKpiWeekCurrentUnit: Double?
var myKpiWeekOutletName: String?
var myKpiWeekTypeOfReward: String?
var myKpiWeekOutletAddress: String?
var myKpiWeekMaxUnit: Double?

required init?(map: Map) {

}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    myKpiWeekBonusStatus <- map["myKpiWeekBonusStatus"]
    myKpiWeekEndDate <- map["myKpiWeekEndDate"]
    myKpiWeekActivatedUnit <- map["myKpiWeekActivatedUnit"]
    myKpiWeekStartDate <- map["myKpiWeekStartDate"]
    myKpiWeekMinUnit <- map["myKpiWeekMinUnit"]
    myKpiWeekCurrentUnit <- map["myKpiWeekCurrentUnit"]
    myKpiWeekOutletName <- map["myKpiWeekOutletName"]
    myKpiWeekTypeOfReward <- map["myKpiWeekTypeOfReward"]
    myKpiWeekOutletAddress <- map["myKpiWeekOutletAddress"]
    myKpiWeekMaxUnit <- map["myKpiWeekMaxUnit"]
}
}
```

Comment: Why your value is null in second response?

Comment: Because they don't have data for next month

Comment: If there is no data available then send empty array not null. even in `myKpiMonthList` doesn't contain null array. There is no logic  that null value in array at index 2.

Comment: It's sending null so that we can show second cell blank tableview.Our req. is like if any month data is null then I need to show blank cell for that month.

Comment: You can send empty string also. or empty array even. Still there is no any logic for the null value. It always crash.

Comment: Yes I asked backend developer to "{}" and now it's working. Thanks @dahiya_boy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no data available then send empty array not `null`. Even in `myKpiMonthList` doesn't contain `null` array. There is no logic that `null` value in array at index 2.

You can send empty string or empty array even. Still there is no any logic for the null value.

Either handle all `null` value from server side else it always crash.